# camera button on photo for uploading images mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add camera button on photo for uploading and updating images directly in asp.net mvc4. Camera button like on facebook profile picture which can add directly photo on clicking the camera button. I am new to asp.net mvc4.

Answer (score -1):

Refer below link for launching device Camera

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/accessing-the-device-camera-with-getusermedia